# How to set value for DevExtreme DxCombobox?

Tags: angularjs, devextreme

How to set the Combobox'value (SelectedBox) from javascript code?

Demo of the component

http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/editors-select_box-search_and_editing/angular/generic/light.compact

I need to set the value from javascript code, I use AngularJS!

from component's api I didn't see how to set it!

http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxSelectBox/?version=15_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [value](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxSelectBox/Configuration/?version=15_2&approach=AngularJS#value) option in the dxSelectBox API. Well, just set this option. If you want to use a two-way binding for the selectbox value, use the [bindingOptions](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Visualization/Basics/Working_with_Widgets/?version=15_2&approach=AngularJS#Change_Options) object.

HTML

```
<div dx-select-box="{dataSource: data, bindingOptions: { value: 'selectedItem' } }"></div>
```

JS

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [/* your data */];
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.data[0];
});
```

I've created the small sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Q892QgGnX302tZte52V?p=preview).